# What information is included when an ADSL modem makes a connection?

Tags: adsl

When an ADSL modem has booted and makes a connection, what information is sent across the wire and what is received? Does this differ if the ADSL modem has been assigned a static IP address or a dynamic IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*What I've figured out so far:*

Most ADSL connections use either PPP over Ethernet over ATM ("PPPoE" mode), or DHCP over Ethernet over ATM ("DHCP" mode).

The former, also called [PPPoE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol_over_Ethernet), uses the same [PPP protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) as used by dial-ups – you authenticate with a username/password and get assigned an address. All packets going to the Internet are tunneled inside this PPP connection, so there's a slight overhead.

PPPoA works the same way, except PPP runs directly over ATM, with no fake-Ethernet in between.

In the second case, your router contacts the ISP's [DHCP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DHCP) directly and (probably) authenticates you based on the physical phone line, and further data packets are sent directly. The DHCP protocol is the same as used in your home network.

The process is the same for both static and dynamic addresses – the DHCP/PPP server is simply told to reserve a specific address for you, instead of picking any available one.

PPP, IP, DHCP and everything else normally goes over [Ethernet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) – but in this case, the Ethernet frames are further encapsulated in [ATM cells](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_Transfer_Mode) and are sent over a statically-configured ATM "virtual circuit". (In case of [PPPoA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PPPoA), there is no Ethernet framing involved – PPP data is sent over ATM directly.)

Finally, everything is converted into electrical signals and sent over the phone line.

- ETHoA: `[ATM [Ethernet [IPv4 [DHCP]]]` → `[ATM [Ethernet [IPv4...]]`
- PPPoE: `[ATM [Ethernet [PPP handshake]]]` → `[ATM [Ethernet [PPP [IPv4...]]]]`
- PPPoA: `[ATM [PPP handshake]]` → `[ATM [PPP [IPv4...]]]`

Comment: Thanks. If most ADSL connections use PPPoE modes, how is that different to PPPoA? Also does that mean PPPoE does not utilize DHCP when being an IP address? When connecting to a DHCP server, is your MAC address provided by the modem?

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: 2) PPP *in any form* does not use DHCP between client and server. The address configuration is done by the PPP protocol, whether over PPP dial-up, PPTP VPN, or PPPo[AE] DSL. (How the *PPP server* allocates addresses is unknown. It *may* be contacting a hidden DHCP server, but that is an implementation detail and nothing the user should be concerned about.)

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey: 3) Yes. The DHCP protocol uses standard IPv4, which is further encapsulated into Ethernet frames. Those Ethernet frames contain the MAC addresses of both ends. (Although note that most ADSL routermodems have the ability to change their MAC addresses, so this is not a secure authentication mechanism... some ISPs still use it, though.)

Comment: Thanks. So seeing that Windows XP has built-in PPPoE functionality, does this mean I can connect directly to the ISP without the need for a modem? I didn't quite understand what you meant by `PPP in any form does not use DHCP between client and server`. When you sau that most ADSL router modems have the ability to change their MAC address, does this occur dynamically or is it user driven?

Comment: 1) No, you still need the modem, to handle the lowest layers - ATM and electrical signals. Also, it's rather inconvenient to have Windows handle it - the modem's PPPoE software usually does a better job.

Comment: 2) The PPP protocol has many uses: it can run over oldschool dial-up, it can run over Ethernet and ATM (PPPoE and PPPoA for ADSL), it can run over existing IP networks (PPTP virtual private network). This is what I meant by many forms. The client and server refer to, in this case, you and your ISP.

Comment: 3) The change is user-driven (usually called "MAC cloning" in the modem settings page), but very rarely required: for example, if you change the modem and your ISP requires the old address.

Comment: What do you mean by `The change is user-driven (usually called "MAC cloning" in the modem settings page), but very rarely required: for example, if you change the modem and your ISP requires the old address`

Comment: @Peanuts: You asked *"When you sau that most ADSL router modems have the ability to change their MAC address, does this occur dynamically or is it user driven?"*. MAC addresses usually are static, but there are some *rare* cases when your modem's MAC addresses have to be changed. For example, some ISPs expect the modem's address to always remain the same, and if you buy a new modem with a new address you might be unable to connect. In those cases, the MAC address can be changed through the modem's settings webpage.